# How to add Workspace Switcher indicator in Docky?

Tags: docky, workspace-switcher

As the title of the question says, how can I add Workspace Switcher indicator in Docky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the dock - Go to **Settings** and then **Docklets**- There is a Workspace Switcher- Click Plus (Add) button.

(Make sure you have not disabled workspaces from System Settings)

[image]