# Add workspace matrix to panel

Tags: panel, workspace-switcher

I'm setting up a laptop with Ubuntu 22.04. I'm used to showing the Workspace Matrix on the bottom panel, and being able to drag windows across to different workspaces.

Is there a way to do this with 22.04? I can use the windows-button to pull the matrix up on the screen, but I found my old way to be more convenient.

---

sudo vi /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js        # Set MAX_THUMBNAILS=20. Was =6.

gnome-extensions disable workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com

gnome-extensions enable  workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com

---

Well.... I just noticed that the switcher shows on my panel if I only have 5 workspaces. After that it disappears.
I'm going to close this issue since it doesn't describe a real problem, and figure out why I'm being limited to 5.

Comment: Here are related threads

https://askubuntu.com/questions/116801/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-workspace

https://askubuntu.com/questions/588470/how-to-add-workspace-switcher-indicator-in-docky

Comment: I am able to use a pop-up to select workspaces, but this doesn't show the windows so I can't drag anything between them.

Comment: the comments section is where we ask you questions to clarify. Please don't add to the comment trail with further information, [edit] your question instead 